# Schur's Lemma: Is the isormorphism between two irreducible spaces unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose $V_1 \neq V_2$ are two irreducible representations of the finite group G. Then Schur's Lemma says that any G-invariant map between them is either 0 or an Isormorphism. I understand that if $V_1 = V_2 = V$ then any automorphism is a scalar multiple and it is proved by considering eigen spaces.

QHowever if these two vector spaces are not the same then what can I say about the isomorphism between them? Is it unique upto a scalar multiple? How does one prove this since I cannot consider eigen spaces.

Comment: Consider any two isomorphism $f_1,f_2$. Then $f_1 f_2^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $V_2$ and hence scalar multiplication. So $f_1=f_1f_2^{-1}f_2$ is scalar multiple of $f_2$. On the other hand is each scalar multiple of $f_2$ again an isomorphism (if the scalar is non-zero).

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should definitely also read rschwieb's excellent answer. It follows the same basic approach and gives solves the problem in a more general setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to speak more generally of $A$ modules for an $F$-algebra $A$, $F$ a field. This would apply to the algebra $F[G]$ for use in representation theory.

As Schur's theorem says, $D=\mathrm{End}(V_A)$ is a division ring if $V$ is a simple right $A$ module.

Now, for any particular element $a\in D$ and $f\in F$, $fa$ is indeed another isomorphism of $V$, but in principal there are more than just the $F$ scalar multiplies. In fact, all of the $D$ scalar multiples are isomorphisms as well! (Elements of $d$ multiply on the left of the isomorphism.) You see, $D$ can be larger than $F$, so there might be more things than just the $F$ multiples. So you *can* say that the isomorphisms are unique up to $D$ multiples, but I don't think that's what you were originally aiming for.

Now, $D$ can't be too much larger: $D$ is a finite dimensional-$F$ algebra.
If your field $F$ happened to be algebraically closed (like $\Bbb C$, for example), then there are no proper finite dimensional extensions of $F$, so then $D=F$. In that case, *yes* any isomorphism of $V$ you pick is an $F$ multiple of each other isomorphism.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I am a physicist and not familiar with a lot of the things you have mentioned. I am considering representations of symmetric groups-regular representations. Do these caveats apply there?

Comment: Dear @Prag1 : Representation theory of a group $G$ over a field $F$ is equivalent to the module theory of the group ring $F[G]$. "Simple module" and "irreducible representation" become synonyms in this context. So, as far as I can see, if you are studying an irreducible representation of a group over an algebraically closed field (like $\Bbb C$) then your conclusion that the endomorphisms of an irreducible representation are unique up to multiplication by $F$ is true.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Now I am worried since I considering regular representions of permutation groups over the field $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Prag1 By regular representation, you're referring to the group acting on itself, right? And then you are considering irreducible subrepresentations?

Comment: Yes. that's right

Comment: More precisely I am thinking of Young diagrams/ tableaux and the equivalent representations of different tableaux of the same diagram

Comment: @Prag1 : It's *possible* that the particular groups of symmetries rule out the finite extensions of $\Bbb R$ (there are only two: $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$ ) but I am not certain. I don't know enough about the groups (or Young diagrams or tableaux) to say definitively. Sorry :(

Comment: Naively! by this do you mean that by acting with any element of the permutation group on an algebra element with real coefficients, we are not going to generate an element with complex coefficients? Sorry If this is too stupid. Your suggestions have been really helpful thanks in any case.

Comment: @Prag1 : I don't know if that intuition works or not. The complex numbers are really natural, so I wouldn't be surprised if they crept in. Perhaps you'll find what you need at the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group

Comment: If I may add something: The character table of the symmetric group only has real entries ($x$ and $x^{-1}$ are conjugate for all $x$) hence the only possibilities for the endomorphisms of an irreducible representation are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{H}$. A quick google search does not turn up any results which would yield that any irred. rep. of any symmetric group is realizible over the reals (cf Frobenius-Schurr-indicator) so this is at least not trivial I would assume.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I have an explicit map. If I find one eigen vector that is real then does the argument follow through,i.e uniqueness.